# OnClick attribute not working when clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having issues with the onclick function, I am trying to run the following code. I am trying to change the text when the button is clicked.

JS

```
function close() {
  document.getElementById('closed').innerHTML = 'We are not ready yet!';
  console.warn('I am working boss');
}
```

Html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>AFLRP is now AUG</title>

<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/assets/favicons/apple-touch-icon.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/assets/favicons/favicon-32x32.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/assets/favicons/favicon-16x16.png">
<link rel="manifest" href="/assets/favicons/site.webmanifest">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/assets/favicons/favicon.ico">
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#2b5797">
<meta name="msapplication-config" content="/assets/favicons/browserconfig.xml">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#0063bf">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cssKits/generalKit.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cssKits/navbarKit.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cssKits/loadingKit.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cssKits/fontKit.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cssKits/contentKit.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cssKits/gridKit.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cssKits/loadingKit.css">
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <meta name="keywords" content="Flashing Lights,RP,Role Play,FL, Australia, Australian, Police, Fire, EMS, Paramedic">
     <meta name="author" content="AFLRP Web Division">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="Enjoy a great Role Play with Aussie Flashing Lights Role Play, be a police officer, fire fighter or EMT and have fun with friends!">
</head>
<body onload="timeOutCheck()" style="margin: 0;">

    <div id="loader"></div>
    <div id="page" style="display: none;">
    <div id="nav">
        <div id="navItem"><a href="index.html" class="navLinkActive">Home</a></div>
        <div id="navItem"><a href="contact.html" class="navLink">Contact</a></div>
        <div id="navItem"><a href="join.html" class="navLink">Join</a></div>
        <div id="navItem"><a href="about.html" class="navLink">About</a></div>
        <div id="navItem"><a href="resources.html" class="navLink">Resources</a></div>
    </div>
    <div id="mainBodyContent" align="center">
    <h1>AFLRP is now Aussie Games</h1>
    <p>AFLRP is becoming Aussie Games, so right now we are not accepting new members and or messages, once we are ready (July 10), we will change this to invite you to AUG</p>
    <button class="disabled" id='closed' onclick="close()" > Join Aussie Games today!"</button>
    </div>

</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

However it isn't changing the text or outputting my test warning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`close()` is a DOM [method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_close.asp). Try changing it to something else

Answer (score 2):

The `close()` is a native JS method -> `window.close()`.
You might want to change your function name.

```js
function closeInvite() {
  document.getElementById('closed').innerHTML = 'We are not ready yet!';
  console.warn('I am working boss');
}
```

```html
<div id="mainBodyContent" align="center">
  <h1>AFLRP is now Aussie Games</h1>
  <p>AFLRP is becoming Aussie Games, so right now we are not accepting new members and or messages, once we are ready (July 10), we will change this to invite you to AUG</p>
  <button class="disabled" id='closed' onclick="closeInvite()"> Join Aussie Games today!"</button>
</div>
```